# Calculate actual duration between numerous start and end times in vbscript

Tags: datetime, vbscript

I have to work out the duration of systems user per day.  So, I have various processes that run at various times of the day.  What I need to do is merge all the timelines into one time line and then work out the duration from there.  My problem is figuring out the overlapping times.

For example:
Process 1 runs from 08:00 to 10:00
Process 2 runs from 09:00 to 13:00
Process 3 runs from 15:00 to 19:00
Process 4 runs from 06:00 to 08:00

What I need as an end result for the time line is:
Time line is 06:00 to 13:00, 15:00 to 19:00

I can work out the duration from that, it is just getting that that final timeline.

Any suggestion on the approach?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a sorted list of your spans and a loop than combines overlapping spans and creates new ones if there is a gap between adjacent spans. To get you started, this proof of concept code

```
  Dim sData
  For Each sData In Array( _
      "08:00-10:00 09:00-13:00 18:00-20:00 15:00-19:00 06:00-08:00" _
    , "08:00-10:00 09:00-13:00 18:00-20:00 15:00-19:00 06:00-08:00 11:00-16:00" _
    , "08:00-10:00 09:00-13:00 18:00-20:00 15:00-19:00 06:00-08:00 11:00-22:00" _
  )
        Dim alData : Set alData = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
        Dim sSpan
        For Each sSpan In Split(sData)
            alData.Add sSpan
        Next
        alData.Sort
        For Each sSpan In alData
            WScript.Echo sSpan
        Next
        WScript.Echo "-------------"
        Dim aFromTo  : aFromTo      = Split(alData(0), "-")
        Dim alResult : Set alResult = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
        Dim nCmp     : nCmp         = 0
        alResult.Add aFromTo(0)
        alResult.Add aFromTo(1)
        Dim i
        For i = 1 To (alData.Count - 1)
            aFromTo = Split(alData(i), "-")
            WScript.Echo alResult(nCmp), "-", alResult(nCmp + 1), " cmp ", aFromTo(0), "-", aFromTo(1)
            Select Case True
              Case aFromTo(0) <= alResult(nCmp + 1)
                If aFromTo(1) > alResult(nCmp + 1) Then
                   alResult(nCmp + 1) = aFromTo(1)
                End If
                WScript.Echo "Combine ==>", alResult(nCmp), "-", alResult(nCmp + 1)
              Case aFromTo(0) > alResult(nCmp + 1)
                alResult.Add aFromTo(0)
                alResult.Add aFromTo(1)
                nCmp = nCmp + 2
                WScript.Echo "New span", alResult(nCmp), "-", alResult(nCmp + 1)
              Case Else
                WScript.Echo "Surprise"
            End Select
        Next
        WScript.Echo "-------------"
        For i = 0 To (alResult.Count - 1) Step 2
            WScript.Echo alResult(i + 0) & " to " & alResult(i + 1)
        Next
        WScript.Echo "#############"
  Next
```

output:

```
06:00-08:00
08:00-10:00
09:00-13:00
15:00-19:00
18:00-20:00
-------------
06:00 - 08:00  cmp  08:00 - 10:00
Combine ==> 06:00 - 10:00
06:00 - 10:00  cmp  09:00 - 13:00
Combine ==> 06:00 - 13:00
06:00 - 13:00  cmp  15:00 - 19:00
New span 15:00 - 19:00
15:00 - 19:00  cmp  18:00 - 20:00
Combine ==> 15:00 - 20:00
-------------
06:00 to 13:00
15:00 to 20:00
#############
06:00-08:00
08:00-10:00
09:00-13:00
11:00-16:00
15:00-19:00
18:00-20:00
-------------
06:00 - 08:00  cmp  08:00 - 10:00
Combine ==> 06:00 - 10:00
06:00 - 10:00  cmp  09:00 - 13:00
Combine ==> 06:00 - 13:00
06:00 - 13:00  cmp  11:00 - 16:00
Combine ==> 06:00 - 16:00
06:00 - 16:00  cmp  15:00 - 19:00
Combine ==> 06:00 - 19:00
06:00 - 19:00  cmp  18:00 - 20:00
Combine ==> 06:00 - 20:00
-------------
06:00 to 20:00
#############
06:00-08:00
08:00-10:00
09:00-13:00
11:00-22:00
15:00-19:00
18:00-20:00
-------------
06:00 - 08:00  cmp  08:00 - 10:00
Combine ==> 06:00 - 10:00
06:00 - 10:00  cmp  09:00 - 13:00
Combine ==> 06:00 - 13:00
06:00 - 13:00  cmp  11:00 - 22:00
Combine ==> 06:00 - 22:00
06:00 - 22:00  cmp  15:00 - 19:00
Combine ==> 06:00 - 22:00
06:00 - 22:00  cmp  18:00 - 20:00
Combine ==> 06:00 - 22:00
-------------
06:00 to 22:00
#############
```

should make experiments (and bug fixing) easy.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was sort of on the right direction, I just didn't add a second array to store the info, that is where I was making a mistake.  I would have got there eventually but you made it a lot quicker for me.  Thanks again.  Very, very good answer.